# In pdf.js viewer, parseQueryString(query) method not working properly when parameter got included

Tags: javascript, servlets, web-applications, pdf.js

[image: Url parameter value got truncated]

With Reference of below pic, In parseQueryString(query) method even while query have full path with parameter along with its value, (mediaName = TestPDF.pdf (with reference of below pic)), at the end of the method the params return the query without value of the parameter which is "/ServePDF?mediaName" but it was supposed to "/ServePDF?mediaName=TestPDF.pdf"

Comment: No one is going to retype a picture. I doubt you would. Show your code as text please. Its not only house rules, its common courtesy

Comment: Then dont strain bro.. 
I have got solution from the below link:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9085

Thanks Anyways.!